# Terminate called throwning an exception

Tags: objective-c, video

I have make a piece of code for playing a video file. But when i build it i get the folowing error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
>        First throw call stack:
>       (0x1ed8022 0x11c0cd6 0x1e80a48 0x1e809b9 0xc6553b 0xc654c5 0x2be8 0x1ed9e99 0x32614e 0x3260e6 0x3ccade 0x3ccfa7 0x3cc266 0x34b3c0 0x34b5e6 0x331dc4 0x325634 0x17baef5 0x1eac195 0x1e10ff2 0x1e0f8da 0x1e0ed84 0x1e0ec9b 0x17b97d8 0x17b988a 0x323626 0x29b2 0x2925)
>       terminate called throwing an exception

I have tried a lot to fix it but nothing does work! Do you no a solution? And yes, i have implementated the mediaplayer framework!

I have coded the follwing code:

```
-(IBAction)playvideo {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"film" ofType:@"mp4"]];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                     initWithContentURL:url];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];

    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];

    [playercontroller release];

    playercontroller = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is described in this line:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Which is telling you that you are passing a `nil` into a parameter that doesn't allow a `nil`.

Steps to be sure that this is the problem:

```
-(IBAction)playvideo {
    NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"film" ofType:@"mp4"]

    if (!videoPath) {
        NSLog(@"Video path is nil. My bundle must be set up incorrectly");
        return; // return early.
    }

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                     initWithContentURL:url];

    // The rest of your implementation here. 

}
```

This should at least help you to localise the problem.

As an aside - you should be using the URL based methods for getting resources instead of string based file-paths. But one thing at a time.

Comment: I have tested it and i get the NSLog! What now?

Comment: As it says - you don't have the file in your bundle where you expect it to be. Are you adding the file in the resources? Is it in a subdirectory? Does it have exactly the same name?

Comment: It obviously isn't as it's logging the condition where it can't find a file where you expect it to be.